# Maven Dependencies .jar non existing library

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

```
The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\.m2\repository\com\portal\pcm\12.0.3\pcm-12.0.3.jar'
```

If i check the folder there are files that have the same name as the jar but end on **jar.lastUpdated.**

I tried maven clean and maven update which did not work. I delete the ***.jar.lastUpdated** in m2, but did not work too.

The line in my pom.xml is:

```
Missing artifact com.portal:pcm:jar:12.0.3
Missing artifact com.portal:pcmext:jar:12.0.3
Missing artifact com.portal:pcmext:jar:12.0.3
```

This block is the one with the marker where it states the artifact is missing.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>pcm</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>pcmext</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>pfc</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

I tried to use a version suggested by mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.portal.pcm/pcm/7.5, but didnt work too.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.portal.pcm</groupId>
    <artifactId>pcm</artifactId>
    <version>7.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.portal.pcm</groupId>
    <artifactId>pcmext</artifactId>
    <version>7.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.portal.pcm</groupId>
    <artifactId>pfc</artifactId>
    <version>7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

i guess dependency configuration is incorrect, but which is correct?

Comment: What do you have in your settings.xml in .m2 folder? Do you have those artefacts published in which repository?

Comment: This dependency does not exist in central repository. You have to use a repository manager and configure the appropriate repository in your repository

Comment: I tried to use artefacts published in mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.portal.pcm/pcm/7.5, i just copy and add in pom.xml. I have to add in settings.xml too?

Comment: The mvnrepository.com is not a consumable maven repository...